# How to position text appropriately under an image independant on the height of the image

Tags: javascript, css

What would be the best method for positioning a set of text under an image regardless of the size of the image?

For example, in the following image I have the first set of images and the second.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWxhK.jpg

The first set of images, the font text is underneath of the images but this is dependent on the images height.

The second set is how I would like for it to look - independent on the images height, the font text will always be at the same location for all images.

Would this be something where a JS script is necessary to determine the height and where the position the image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't placing the images in one row of a table and the text legends in the next row do what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the maximum height of the various images, you can wrap each in an identically-sized block, with the caption below that.  This also allows consistent widths.

HTML:

```
<figure>
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
  </div>
  <figcaption>one</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/75" />
  </div>
  <figcaption>two</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
  </div>
  <figcaption>three</figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgwrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

A working example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/auLcA

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to **emulate a table layout** with divs and CSS.

**This works without having to have an absolute height for *anything.***

### [**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3nQa/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000/fff" />
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" />
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.cell img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Edit:** There are a few caveats with `display:table` layouts concerning IE compatibility and responsiveness; see Paul's comment.

Comment: Caveats: `table-cell` isn't supported in IE 7 and lower, if those are relevant to your audience. Won't reflow/fill-in more images per line as browser width increases (or use fewer images per line on smaller screens).